# Connection refused with telnet, curl works

Tags: curl, telnet

I have a problem with setting up an appliance right now, which has to connect to some websites.

I have noticed that using curl works on the websites I need, but using telnet on port 80/443 gives an connection refused.

We have tested it on another location and telnet + curl works as intended. So can anyone explain me the difference between curl and telnet? Thanks for your help! :)

example:

Location 1:

curl google.com:80 -> website moved...

telnet google.com 80 -> connection refused

Location 2:

curl google.com:80 -> website moved...

telnet google.com 80 -> Escape character ^

Comment: Telnet is a protocol per se but the application allows to connect to a listening port and in some cases do simple tests as an HTTP request or a SMTP sessions. In your case, may be a firewall at location 1 is denying HTTP traffic without a minimum of HTTP headers or could be Windows not allowing telnet to pass thru the firewall.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apples and Oranges. `curl` uses the *HTTP* protocol, while `telnet` uses an entirely different and unrelated protocol (and TCP/IP port number). The two are not related to one another.